# Is it possible to scikit_learn (1.0) under pypy (3.8)?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pypy

I just tried to install package scikit_learn==1.0 under pypy (version 3.8) .

```
pip install scikit_learn==1.0
```

The scikit_learn installation process was failed with the following warnings and errors:

```
            WARNING: CMake Toolchain: Failed to determine CMake compilers state
            Run-time dependency openblas found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)
            Run-time dependency openblas found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)
      
            ../../scipy/meson.build:130:0: ERROR: Dependency "OpenBLAS" not found, tried pkgconfig and cmake
      
            A full log can be found at /tmp/pip-install-lk3y1_ui/scipy_e4d0b1a6282a41c8a89b0b20a1fd06fd/.mesonpy-9_78imws/build/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
            + meson setup --native-file=/tmp/pip-install-lk3y1_ui/scipy_e4d0b1a6282a41c8a89b0b20a1fd06fd/.mesonpy-native-file.ini -Ddebug=false -Doptimization=2 --prefix=/usr /tmp/pip-install-lk3y1_ui/scipy_e4d0b1a6282a41c8a89b0b20a1fd06fd /tmp/pip-install-lk3y1_ui/scipy_e4d0b1a6282a41c8a89b0b20a1fd06fd/.mesonpy-9_78imws/build
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/home/george/Documents/python_test2/myenv/lib/pypy3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
                main()
              File "/home/george/Documents/python_test2/myenv/lib/pypy3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
                json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
              File "/home/george/Documents/python_test2/myenv/lib/pypy3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 130, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
                return hook(config_settings)
              File "/tmp/pip-build-env-v7f76qdj/overlay/lib/pypy3.8/site-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 923, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
                with _project(config_settings) as project:
              File "/usr/lib/pypy3.8/contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
                return next(self.gen)
              File "/tmp/pip-build-env-v7f76qdj/overlay/lib/pypy3.8/site-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 903, in _project
                build_dir=config_settings.get('builddir'),
              File "/usr/lib/pypy3.8/contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
                return next(self.gen)
              File "/tmp/pip-build-env-v7f76qdj/overlay/lib/pypy3.8/site-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 547, in with_temp_working_dir
                yield cls(source_dir, tmpdir, build_dir)
              File "/tmp/pip-build-env-v7f76qdj/overlay/lib/pypy3.8/site-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 463, in __init__
                self._configure(reconfigure=bool(build_dir) and not native_file_mismatch)
              File "/tmp/pip-build-env-v7f76qdj/overlay/lib/pypy3.8/site-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 500, in _configure
                *setup_args,
              File "/tmp/pip-build-env-v7f76qdj/overlay/lib/pypy3.8/site-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 477, in _meson
                return self._proc('meson', *args)
              File "/tmp/pip-build-env-v7f76qdj/overlay/lib/pypy3.8/site-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 472, in _proc
                subprocess.check_call(list(args))
              File "/usr/lib/pypy3.8/subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
                raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
            subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['meson', 'setup', '--native-file=/tmp/pip-install-lk3y1_ui/scipy_e4d0b1a6282a41c8a89b0b20a1fd06fd/.mesonpy-native-file.ini', '-Ddebug=false', '-Doptimization=2', '--prefix=/usr', '/tmp/pip-install-lk3y1_ui/scipy_e4d0b1a6282a41c8a89b0b20a1fd06fd', '/tmp/pip-install-lk3y1_ui/scipy_e4d0b1a6282a41c8a89b0b20a1fd06fd/.mesonpy-9_78imws/build']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
            [end of output]
```

I was wondering if there is a solution to this issue and if scikit_learn (this version or newer) is compatible with pypy.

Comment: what happens if you don't pin the version?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be complaining that it wants to compile scikit learn but you haven’t installed non-python dependencies (such as the BLAS linear algebra library or corresponding development headers).

According to the [FAQ](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/faq.html) the pypy support exists but is experimental.